# Как переключить select?

Tags: javascript, html

Вообщем, пишу я небольшой бот на puppeter который собирает информацию, и мне нужно переключить select на странице програмно, я его переключаю:

```
document.querySelector('#order').querySelectorAll('option')[2].selected = 'selected';
```

Он переключается, но дальше ничего не происходит. То есть, новые данные, которые должны соответствовать новому селекту, не появляются.

Comment: предположу что "новые данные" должны появляться при событии `change` данного селекта, и так, как при программном изменении значения ивент на чейндж не фаириться, его нужно позвать самому, собственно при изминении данных

Answer (score 1):

Для этого надо выбирать не option, а менять сам select и его value

```
document.querySelector('#order').value = document.querySelector('#order').querySelectorAll('option')[2].value;
```

Либо изменить с помощью selectedIndex, если надо по индексу

```
document.querySelector('#order').selectedIndex = 2;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BaNru/ub65po0n/